# Strange bucket sort benchmark results?

Tags: java, sorting, benchmarking

**Benchmark Results**

This bucket sort becomes more efficient even though there are increasingly more elements in the list. I'm looking for an answer to point me in the right direction to understand why this happens.

```
Test:[1]  | Average Bench Time:[11ms]  | Elements Sorted:[1 000 000]
Test:[2]  | Average Bench Time:[11ms]  | Elements Sorted:[2 000 000]
Test:[3]  | Average Bench Time:[4ms]   | Elements Sorted:[3 000 000]
Test:[4]  | Average Bench Time:[7ms]   | Elements Sorted:[4 000 000]
Test:[5]  | Average Bench Time:[7ms]   | Elements Sorted:[5 000 000]
Test:[6]  | Average Bench Time:[10ms]  | Elements Sorted:[6 000 000]
Test:[7]  | Average Bench Time:[12ms]  | Elements Sorted:[7 000 000]
Test:[8]  | Average Bench Time:[12ms]  | Elements Sorted:[8 000 000]
Test:[9]  | Average Bench Time:[15ms]  | Elements Sorted:[9 000 000]
Test:[10] | Average Bench Time:[17ms]  | Elements Sorted:[10 000 000]
```

Here the the sorting code

```
 public void Sort() {
        int[] bucket = new int[getMax() + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            bucket[data[i]] = bucket[data[i]] + 1;

        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bucket.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < bucket[i]; k++) {
                data[index] = i;
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm unsure if non-code related questions are acceptable.

**Logical flow of events**

- Each test is given a max size to populate an array.
- Randomized integers are placed into each index, filling the entire array
- The system time is stored
- The list is sorted
- The system time is compared
- The result is displayed

Comment: `bucket[data[i]]++` is [CountingSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (histogram then fill), not [BucketSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).  Bucket Sort is more like Radix Sort.

Comment: But anyway, did you warm up the CPU and the JVM JIT before the first 2 sort calls?  If not, you may be seeing CPU frequency ramp-up and/or the JVM only making a fully optimized version of the function for the 3rd call.